# want to clear contents of stage in actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am new to flash and actionscript.
I have added some movie clips to the stage using addChild method on Some Mouse Events.

Now on an event say Mouse Double Click I want to clean the stage.

I checked the Stage class from reference it does not have any method called clear.
Neither I have stored the references of the objects, so that i can clear them using removeChild()

How to go about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend keeping the references of the objects in an array.

Barring that, you could do this (off the top of my head):

```
while(numChildren > 0) {
    removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Depending on the location of this code, you may need to prepend stage. to numChildren and removeChildAt. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if( numChildren )
{
    removeAllChildren();
}
```